# Is there a C# equivalent of Java's LineNumberReader?

Tags: c#

Is there a C# equivalent of Java's [LineNumberReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html)?

i.e. a `StreamReader.ReadLine()` which kept count of the line number.  Or is the only way to achieve this by creating a custom subclass of [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx), and implement the necessary counting in an overridden method?

Comment: There isn't, but it is trivial to implement one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in the .NET Framework.

If you create a custom class, I recommend you create a class that extends [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) and wraps a [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) instance, so it can be used with any [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) subclass ([StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx), [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx)).

At a minimum, you need to override the [TextReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx) and [TextReader.Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.peek.aspx) methods. For efficiency, you should also override all the other virtual methods of the [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) class.

```
class LineNumberTextReader : TextReader
{
    private readonly TextReader reader;
    private int b;
    private int line;

    public LineNumberTextReader(TextReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public int Line
    {
        get { return this.line; }
    }

    public override int Peek()
    {
        return this.reader.Peek();
    }

    public override int Read()
    {
        int b = this.reader.Read();
        if ((this.b == '\n') || (this.b == '\r' && b != '\n')) this.line++;
        return this.b = b;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) this.reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a functionality. You have to keep a local variable and increment or implement a simple StreamReader:

```
public class CustomStreamReader : StreamReader
{
    private int _lineNumber  = 0;

    public CustomStreamReader(Stream stream)
        : base(stream)
    {
    }

    public int LineNumber 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _lineNumber;
        } 
    }

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        _lineNumber++;
        return base.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Bear in mind, this class assumes you only initialise it with a `Stream` and you will only call `ReadLine()`. Otherwise you have to fully override to make sure `LineNumber` is valid.